# Find nibs using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I know how to remove autolayout from a specific nib etc...

Is there any way to turn it off for an entire project?

If not, is there a way to find the nibs that have it enabled so I know which ones to turn off?

Thanks

Comment: Nope.  It's on a NIB by NIB basis unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's a nib setting rather than a project setting. I guess you could grep all the .xib files for the relevant flag, as they're just XML, but I don't know what that flag is.